# Gitlab azure cli multiple lines parameters

Tags: bash, gitlab, azure-cli

I'm trying to create a ci pipeline in Gitlab to create a new storage account. As this resources has lots of optional parameters, putting it all on one line makes it quite long so I wanted to break it up. Running it in my local bash instance works fine but not on gitlab. How can I split commands into several rows in gitlab? This is how my CI looks like:

```
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:2.9.1

stages:
  - preparation

create_storage:
  stage: preparation
  script:
    # Create storage account if not exists:
    - storageAccountAvailable=$(az storage account check-name --name myStorage --query "nameAvailable")
    - >
      if [[ $storageAccountAvailable = "true" ]]; then
        az group create --location westeurope --name myStorageRG
        az storage account create \
          --name myStorage \
          --resource-group myStorageRG \
          --sku Standard_LRS \
          --min-tls-version TLS1_2 \
          --https-only true \
          --access-tier Hot \
          --default-action Deny \
          --public-network-access Disabled

        az storage account network-rule add --account-name myStorage --ip-address 1.1.1.1
      fi
  allow_failure: false
```

If I use backslashes like above, it fails on the last row, `--public-network-access Disabled`, saying its not recognizing the argument. If I remove the backslashes entirely it fails at the beggining and complaings that I am missing the resourcesgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Split Long commands into multiple lines to view a better readability. So you can use the **literal** `|`  and **folded** `>` (). Refer [YAML multiline block scalar indicators](https://yaml-multiline.info/).

According to the [Gitlab Doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#split-long-commands) we came to know,

> **If multiple commands are combined into one command string, only the last command’s failure or success is reported. [Failures from earlier commands are ignored due to a bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/25394). To work around this, run each command as a separate `script` item, or add an `exit 1` command to each command string.**